# ERROR: Error parsing url: undefined when migrating database to heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize as an ORM and I'm trying to migrate my database to Heroku. When running `heroku run sequelize db:migrate`

I just get

```
Loaded configuration file "config/config.js".
Using environment "production".
ERROR: Error parsing url: undefined
```

Here's what my config file looks like:

```
  module.exports = {
  "development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "password",
    "database": "vueapp",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "production": {
    "use_env_variable": process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    "dialect": "postgres",
    "ssl": true,
    "dialectOptions": {
      "ssl": true
    }
  }
}
```

And the index file

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config')[env];

const User = require("./user")
const Hour = require('./hours');

const db = {
  User,
  Hour
};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.use_env_variable, config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Not entirely sure what the issue is. Going through the heroku logs, I see a `throw new Error('Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0');`

But I have added the dialect in the config.js file. Does it matter if the config file is a .js file or a .json file?

Just to clarify, the actual web app opens up and I can see the error handler that I set up. So I'm not actually getting an application error when opening up the route URL

Comment: Did you later solve the problem. I need help

Answer (score 1):

production: {
    use_env_variable: 'DATABASE_URL',
  },

change your production to this and go to heroku to set environmental variable

Answer (score 0):

Did you later solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is a little confusing but Damilola is correctly.  You need need to leave the value for use_env_variable to 'DATABASE_URL'.  You will be tempted to change this to process.env.DATABASE_URL.  This is incorrect.

Leaving it like this will allow Sequelize to inject the value that is saved to the Heroku env variable DATABASE_URL.

production: {
use_env_variable: 'DATABASE_URL',
dialect: "postgres",
protocol: "postgres"
}